# Replace value in rows (does not meet condition) with next closest row (meets condition)

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataframe as shown below. They are ordered Ascendingly by Column A and B. Only Occurrences >= 10 are valid, thus for rows with occurrences with less than 10, I want to replace their values with the next/closest valid row.

| Column A | Column B | Occurrences | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 3 | 2 | 0 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 4 | 10 | 5 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 5 | 1 | 1 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 6 | 12 | 4 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 1 | 1 | 7 |

Here is what the final dataframe should look like. I would like to do this in Bigquery but if its not possible, python would work as well.

| Column A | Column B | Occurrences | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | 1 | 5 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 3 | 2 | 5 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 4 | 10 | 5 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 5 | 1 | 4 |
| Cell 1 | Cell 6 | 12 | 4 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 1 | 1 | 4 |

I have the dataframe all set up, but just having trouble figuring out the logic to apply this.

Logic:

1. Start from the top and go through each row to check number of occurrences.
2. If occurrences <10, look for the next valid row and take that value replace the non-valid row.
3. If the last row is non-valid, it should take the value from previous row that is valid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# example dataframe
dict = {'Column A': ['Cell 1', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 2'],
      'Column B': ['Cell 2', 'Cell 3', 'Cell 4', 'Cell 5', 'Cell 6', 'Cell 1'],
      'Occurrences': [1, 2, 10, 1, 12, 1],
      'Value': [0, 0, 5, 1, 4, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# if Occurrences < 10, set Value to nan
df.loc[df['Occurrences'] < 10, 'Value'] = np.nan

# use interpolate and fillna to set missing (nan) values to nearest non-missing row value
# (first use bfill or "backfill" method, so take the value from the "next" valid row; then apply the ffill or
# "forwardfill" method for any rows at the end that were not filled)
df.loc[:, 'Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Note that if you just want to fill these values with the **nearest** row value, you can use [Series.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) with method='nearest'

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below approach in BigQuery

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(Value),
       -- Logic #3. If the last row is non-valid,
       -- it should take the value from previous row that is valid.
       COALESCE(Value, LAST_VALUE(Value IGNORE NULLS) OVER w1) AS Value
  FROM (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(value),
           -- Logic #2, If occurrences <10, look for the next valid row 
           -- and take that value replace the non-valid row.
           FIRST_VALUE(IF(Occurrences < 10, NULL, Value) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w0 AS Value
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (ORDER BY columnA, columnB ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  )
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY columnA, columnB ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

**Query results**

[image]